# How to multiply numpy arrays with a condition?

Tags: python, numpy

I change the brightness of a 16-bit image, for this I use numpy arrays. I'm multiplying an array of 16-bit values by an array of coefficients I need.
`array0[a:b] = array0[a:b] * array1` But I need the values not to exceed 65535, even if the product is greater than 65535. Perhaps there is a ready-made solution for multiplying arrays with a similar condition? Perhaps I could use numpy.where, but the problem is that if the value of 65535 is exceeded, then the countdown will continue from zero, that is, for example, if the expected multiplication result is 65540, then the value of the element will be 65540-65535 = 5

First, I tried to create a 32-bit array, copy the data into it, perform multiplication, then equate values exceeding 65535 to 65535. Then enter the received values into the source array. The problem is also that I'm using a slice of the array, not the entire array. Perhaps there is a more effective solution?

Comment: Use [`clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html): `np.clip(array0[a:b].astype(np.uint64) * array1, 0, 65535)`